# Driving laser modules with MCP23017 and MOSFETs

Tags: mosfet, laser, expander, esp32

I would like to make a PCB to switch 16 laser modules on and off.

The laser module in question is this one: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9906

I believe the module already has a driver included (there's an IC on it), so I shouldn't be too worried about directly controlling the laser diode, instead I will just need to power it.

The maximum power draw is 300mA but Sparkfun was able to boost it to 400mA.

So I thought of using an IO expander like the MCP23017 since the ESP32 board that I'm using doesn't have too many digital pins left over.

The IO expander then is connected to the gate of an N-channel MOSFET: the MMBF170LT1G. This has a continuous drain current of 500mA, so it should be enough.

To get the power required for 16 lasers I'm including a couple of SKM10B-03's from MeanWell. These convert incoming 24VDC from an external power supply to 3.3V. To drive 16 lasers at 1W each I'll use two of them.

Is my schematic below correct (just showing one laser for simplicity)? Do I need a resistor between the gate of the MOSFET and the pin of the MCP23017? I first considered using a transistor array instead of individual MOSFETs but I'm not sure they can stand continuous operation of all lasers, since often they share a common ground pin?

Note: The ESP32-PoE-ISO by Olimex already has pull-up resistors for I2C. I also put a 10k resistor on the trim control of the SKM10B, this is to trim the voltage up if needed. I probably won't include the resistor and leave the trim free floating.

[image: Schematic]

Comment: Don't touch that FET it will burn your finger with 5 Ohms and R ja= 556 °C/W . Always choose a FET with >4x your current  and use large heatsink or choose I max rating 10x

Comment: Then make sure your logic level is >=3x the FET Threshold Vgs(th) for low rated RdsOn.

Comment: OK, so a better choice would be the SI2342DS-T1-GE3 by Vishay. 6A continuous drain current, 8V max drain source voltage, 800mV threshold voltage, 2.5W power dissipation in a SOT-23 package.

Comment: Blobkat, req’d the fine print in future  about Pd Board heatsink copper area 2xside

Comment: Sorry Tony, I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: Auto spell correction error..  I meant READ the fine print

Comment: When it says 1.6W bc that means double sided copper FR4 1 square inch with lots of thermal vias in open ambient convection cooled

Comment: OK, I see it now. [This link](https://forum.digikey.com/t/ta-vs-tc-vs-tj-ratings/762) explains the different values (Ta, Tc) to me. That's a huge hassle. Might go for big heatsinks with THT components then. Or relays, I don't need fast switching.

Comment: Better FETs come in SMT but needs large copper heat spreaders.  About 2W sqin is my rule of thumb on. alum Clad and 0.5W/SQIn for SMT on 2x copper